# TeXnicCenter custom build

Tags: compiling, texniccenter

Is there a possibility to setup custom build for TeXnicCenter?
Now all compilation is done using custom make/build cmd bat, however it would be much more convenient to have all this in TeXnicCenter.

Comment: i mean custom build procedure, e.g. now it look like:
pdflatex file.tex
bibtex sometext
bibtex sometext1
pdflatex file.tex

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. TeXnicCenter provides a number of default "build" options (Build > Define Output Profiles...):

[image]

However, you can Add your own:

[image]

Here you can complete the minimum required interaction with LaTeX by suggesting the appropriate compiler, BibTeX and MakeIndex processors. If preprocessing is required, add these steps under the Preprocessor tab. Postprocessing is added under the Postprocessor tab.